# Code style settings won't apply in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

Currently I'm using:

**Visual Studio** Community 2022 for Mac **Preview** <sup>(Because I have an ARM64 machine)</sup>
Version 17.4 Preview (17.4 build 1583)

**VisualStudio** defaults to a code style where each curly brace is on a new line.
I prefer the style used in Java or Swift, where curly braces are not carried to the next line.

I found this setting in **Visual Studio** and changed it to my taste:
[image: Visual Studio Preferences [C# source code]]

However, this setting does not work the way I need: the code is still formatted according to the **default** styles.

[image]

It's worth noting that after clicking on the item: «*Convert to 'Program.Main' style program*», the code is formatted correctly.

This looks like a Visual Studio bug, but I'm not entirely sure. Maybe I missed something?

<sup>P.S. I've tried deleting Visual Studio settings files and creating new projects, but all attempts have been unsuccessful.</sup>

Comment: The following may be useful: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home

Comment: I had the same problem with 17.4. This is not fixed in the preview build 17.5 either. I have now downgraded to 17.3.8 (Build 5) where it works fine.

Comment: Same issue here. @Superpanic how did you downgrade to 17.3.8. I can't find that build anywhere.

Comment: «A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release. We'll update you once it becomes available for download.»